# How to send a JavaScript object along with an html form?

Tags: javascript, forms

I have an HTML form, which has quite a few input fields. As the user types in one of them, JavaScript generates a few objects that contain data I need to get to the server. I know I can send these objects with AJAX, but I need them to end up in the same function as the normal data from the form once they get server-side (I'm using flask for the backend). Is there any way I can send the objects along with the form, so that they somehow end up in the same place?

Here is the beginning of the form:

```html
<form action="/org/new-task" method="post">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <select name="rep-type" class="form-select">
            <option selected disabled>Type of task</option>
            <option value="0">Ongoing/repeating</option>
            <option value="1">One-off</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    ...
```

and here is the output when I `console.log()` one of the objects (there are multiple, but they are very similar):

```
(2) ["painting", "cleaning"]
```

Comment: Any code to show?

Comment: @GetSet no, I don't know how to do this, so I didn't have anything to try. I didn't think posting html would help, since its a pretty generic form. I can if you think I should, though.

Comment: Even posting your html would help on shaping the context of your problem. Posting nothing will lead to guesses, a black box.

Answer (score 2):

To have some objects sent with a "normal" form submit... You could store those in some hidden input elements as string.

You will have to parse that string on the python side. [Look here for how](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp)

```js
let some_object = {
  name: "John",
  last: "Doh"
}

// Stringify the object and store it in the hidden input
let hidden_input = document.querySelector("[name='js_object']")
hidden_input.value = JSON.stringify(some_object)

// Just for this demo... to console log something.
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log(hidden_input.value)
  console.log(typeof(hidden_input.value))
})
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="hidden" name="js_object">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have either a [hidden input](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_hidden.asp) or can [serialize the form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) on [submit and submit it using JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript). It's probably simpler to avoid the DOM updates though and just use JS:

From MDN:

Using FormData bound to a form element
You can also bind a FormData object to an  element. This creates a FormData object that represents the data contained in the form.

The HTML is typical:

```
<form id="myForm">
  <label for="myName">Send me your name:</label>
  <input id="myName" name="name" value="John">
  <input type="submit" value="Send Me!">
</form>
```

But JavaScript takes over the form:

```
window.addEventListener( "load", function () {
  function sendData() {
    const XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Bind the FormData object and the form element
    const FD = new FormData( form );

    // Define what happens on successful data submission
    XHR.addEventListener( "load", function(event) {
      alert( event.target.responseText );
    } );

    // Define what happens in case of error
    XHR.addEventListener( "error", function( event ) {
      alert( 'Oops! Something went wrong.' );
    } );

    // Set up our request
    XHR.open( "POST", "https://example.com/cors.php" );

    // The data sent is what the user provided in the form
    XHR.send( FD );
  }

  // Access the form element...
  const form = document.getElementById( "myForm" );

  // ...and take over its submit event.
  form.addEventListener( "submit", function ( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    sendData();
  } );
} );
```

I'd suggest replacing the XHR with a fetch request though, or using whatever library you're using in place of it. This is the most flexible in that you can now process how you want to send the FormData. You can change it into JSON and make your processing on the server that much easier.

Comment: How does my object end up getting sent? What is it called in this example?